# How do I see all commits that modified file CONTENTS (not metadata)?

Tags: git

`git log --follow` shows me all commits for `FILE`, but what if I only want to see commits that changed the file *contents* rather than metadata (permissions etc.)? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Git doesn't store much metadata for files anyway — it stores only the executable bit, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no.  You can save the found commit hashes (or the entire `git log` output) somewhere and filter them further, but that's not built into Git.